# Dovecot Sieve does not run?

Tags: dovecot, debian-wheezy, sieve

I'm quite new to Dovecot but it has worked out for me pretty good so far for me.
I run dovecot with postfix and amavis and spamassassin and it works out all fine, mails get tagged as junk, sending, receiving, all fine.

Now I wanted to add the sieve plugin so mails get moved on the server and that does not work out. I wanted to start with a general script moving the junk to the junk folder but that is not happening.

So I searched the web and found the troubleshooting, which said, that sieve is propably not running. I did not manage to find any log entries made by sieve so this could be the problem. Here I found that you have to put sieve to the protocols, I guess in dovecot.conf.

I tried and dovecot didnt start anymore posting unkown protocol: sieve.
I added lmtp to the protocols as I want to use it and it was posted in another thread but I got the error: service(lmtp) accces failed: no such file or directory.

Some system infos:
OS: Debian 7
Dovecot Version: 2.1.7

Config Files:
dovecot.conf (reduced on changed/added)

```
protocols = imap pop3

plugin {
    sieve_before = /var/vmail/sieve/spam-global.sieve
    sieve_dir = /var/vmail/%d/%n/sieve/scripts/
    sieve = /var/vmail/%d/%n/sieve/active-script.sieve
}
```

conf.d/20-lmtp.conf (created it)

```
protocol lmtp {  
    # Space separated list of plugins to load (default is global mail_plugins).  
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve  
}
```

spam-global.sieve

```
require "fileinto";  
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {  
    fileinto "Spam";  
}
```

How can I check, wether sieve is running?

Afaik Postfix needs to be configured to work with sieve. I'm not sure I did that so far but as long as sieve wont run, that wont solve the problem right?

Thanks for any help
Invalid

Comment: You are missing the Postfix configuration, Postfix needs deliver via dovecot, as postfix can't handle sieve. See [Dovecot LDA with Postfix](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix)

Answer (score 2):

You say you had to create the file?

Sounds like you never installed the protocol plugin under dovecot.

1. First, DO NOT edit (or create) the installed `conf` files when avoidable. Make your own. Create a `/etc/dovecot/local.cf` OR `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/99-custom.conf` (for example).
2. In newer Dovecot distro versions, the LDA (`15-lda.conf`) plugin is installed by default, but not the LMTP plugin (`20-lmtp.conf`). You can use the LDA plugin. (Local Delivery Agent).
3. If you still wish to use LMTP, you need to install the plugin: `sudo apt install dovecot-lmtpd`. If you had done that, you wouldn't need to create the `.conf` file for it.

The pertinent Sieve areas of my `/etc/dovecot/local.cf`:

```
protocol imap {

  mail_plugins = autocreate
}
plugin {
   autocreate = Spam
   autosubscribe = Spam
}

# SIEVE STUFF
# Include already included protocols and sieve:
protocols = $protocols sieve

# Allow sieve to be run out of LDA plugin/protocol:
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}

# Sieve plugin settings
plugin {
   sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
   sieve_default = /usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
   sieve_global = /usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/
}

# May not need this, but it doesn't hurt:
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
}
```

The pertinent Sieve areas of my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` (using dovecot lda/deliver):

```
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

My `default.sieve`:

```
require ["envelope", "fileinto", "mailbox", "subaddress"];

if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
        fileinto :create "Spam";
}
if header :contains "X-Amavis-Alert" "BAD HEADER SECTION" {
        fileinto :create "Spam";
}
if address :domain "From" "mydomain.net" {
   if not envelope :domain "From" "mydomain.net" {
      fileinto "Spam";
      stop;
   }
}
if address :domain "From" "mydomain.com" {
   if not envelope :domain "From" "mydomain.com" {
      fileinto "Spam";
      stop;
   }
}
```

Pertinent area of `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user` (or make your own: `99-custom`) :

```
@local_domains_acl  = ( [ ".$mydomain", '.mydomain.net', '.mydomain.com' ] );
@local_domains_maps = ( [ ".$mydomain", '.mydomain.net', '.mydomain.com' ] );
# Do not quarantine or trash emails - hand off to LDA instead
$final_spam_destiny=D_PASS;
$final_virus_destiny=D_PASS;
$final_bad_header_destiny=D_PASS;
@addr_extension_spam_maps=('Spam');
```

Restart Dovecot and test port:

```
# sudo systemctl restart dovecot
# telnet 10.10.10.100 4190
Trying 10.10.10.100...
Connected to 10.10.10.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
"IMPLEMENTATION" "Dovecot (Ubuntu) Pigeonhole"
"SIEVE" "fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext"
"NOTIFY" "mailto"
"SASL" "PLAIN"
"STARTTLS"
"VERSION" "1.0"
OK "Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready."
```

Dovecot debug output - can see it working:

```
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib90_sieve_plugin.so
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: Effective uid=1000, gid=1000, home=/home/emailuser1
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/home/emailuser1/Maildir
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: maildir++: root=/home/emailuser1/Maildir, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/home/emailuser1/Maildir, alt=
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: userdb lookup skipped, username taken from USER environment
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: none: root=, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=, alt=
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: Destination address: emailuser1@mydomain.net (source: -a parameter)
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: Pigeonhole version 0.4.21 (92477967) initializing
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: file storage: Storage path `/home/emailuser1/sieve' not found
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: file storage: Storage path `/home/emailuser1/.dovecot.sieve' not found
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: storage: Trying default script location `/usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve'
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using Sieve script path: /usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: file script: Opened script `default' from `/usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve'
2019-05-16 15:29:49 lda(emailuser1): Debug: sieve: Using the following location for user's Sieve script: /usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
```

Sieve now runs. Your question answered.

As far as anything I may have missed - each setup can vary. Please review some articles if you are still stuck. My sieve global rules store quarantine stuff in per-user 'Spam' folders (users are non-virtual). As pointed out, you probably need to edit your postfix main.cf (and master.cf if virtual users/vmail) [as noted here](https://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix) to use Dovecot LDA. You also probably need to edit your content-filter (amavis-new for instance) as noted. There are [articles out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=amavisd-new%20per%20user%20spam%20folders) for this.

Comment: Do you know a debug command to send mails marked as spam directly to dovecot?